# Visual Studio test task fails in pipeline but succeeds in test console

Tags: azure-devops, vstest, vstest.console.exe, vstest.console

I am using [Visual studio test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azdevops) to run all my tests as a part of my build definition. 
The options that I have enabled are as attached below:

[image]

Now, the problem here is that, some of my tests always fail when I run them from the build pipleine , however all of these test seem to pass when I run them via 
vstests console.exe command.

`ex:` `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\VSTest.Console" <path to dll>`

Does anyone have any clue what could be wrong in here?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some of the details from the logs of the pipeline

Comment: Did you solve this? If not, do you have any addl. info on the failing test. Build log and error message etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Installed by tools installer` selection, I would need to see what your tools installation task is doing to provide additional info. Maybe you're not installing a version that is compatible with the tests?

[image]

---

If you don't have a specific need to call out a different test platform version, maybe try using `Latest`.

[image]

**OR**

Since you're calling `...\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\...\VSTest.Console`, you may want to select the `Visual Studio 2015` option.

[image]

Comment: Hi Josh, thank you for the reply. 
I tried with both the options and the tests failed :(